# SSIS Encode a .raw or .txt file from ANSI to UTF-8 without BOM using C#

Tags: c#, utf-8, ssis

I am working on a fairly simple SSIS package, which reads from DB2 using ODBC Source and taking it to a flat file destination. But I need this file that is generated to be UTF-8 (without BOM) and not ANSI as it is automatically generated by SSIS. The closest thing that has worked for me is the code below, but it converts it to UTF-8 BOM and the client tells me that the file with BOM does not work for him. Is there any way I can make the file UTF-8?

```
string srcFilename = Dts.Variables["User::FFDestPath"].Value.ToString();
string text = File.ReadAllText(srcFilename);
File.WriteAllText(srcFilename, text, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
Encoding utf8WithoutBom = new UTF8Encoding(false);
```

Edit:
[image]
[image]

Comment: You don’t seem to be using `utf8WithoutBom` to actually create the file though?

Comment: @stuartd Hi, That line is for not using BOM.

Comment: Ok, but you write the file, then you create `utf8WithoutBom` but you don’t use it? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: I am relatively new to C #, still learning. What do you suggest I should improve on that code to achieve what I need?

Comment: How about `File.WriteAllText(srcFilename, text, utf8WithoutBom)`?

Answer (score 1):

For writing natively in SSIS, in your Flat File Connection manager, specify the Code Page is 65001 (UTF-8).

[image]

When the Flat File Destination writes a file, there is no BOM written.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. My FF Destination looks exactly like that one, when I open the file in Notepad++ is ANSI.

Comment: Crazy - can you post a screenshot of it so I can try an repro? General tab + at least one column from Advanced? Oh and ensure the flat file destination specifies overwrite otherwise it'd never clear the BOM if it was built otherwise.